# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded while populating data with snapshot Real time Firebase JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate the 'results' array with JSON data from Realtime Firebase Database but I get

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at normalizeArrayChildren

```
    <template>
    <div id="show-results">
        <h1>Data</h1>
             <input type="text" v-model="search"  placeholder="search results" />
            <div v-for="result in results" class="single-result">
            <h2>{{ result.Speed }}</h2>
           </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import db from '@/firebase/init'
    import firebase from 'firebase'

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                results: [
                ],
               search: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {

        },
        created() {
    // Issue causing line
        firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => { this.results = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());

}); 
    },

        mounted(){
              console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
 }
```

}

Please answer as the right code to be written to properly take in the JSON in 'results' array and then print each individual document for that JSON.

Comment: Are you trying to read your entire database at one time?

Comment: Yes, I want to store all JSON data in my 'results' array and then print it to the screen.

Comment: That could be a massive amount of data an overwhelm the device. Can you read them in one at a time instead or possibly paginate read say 10 at a time? Also, displaying that much data to the user could overwhelm them as well, so small manageable chunks may be a better option.